# cannot align ion-label to the right end

Tags: angular, ionic2

```
 <ion-card>
<ion-card-content>
 <ion-label>Total Price</ion-label><ion-label text-right>Due Date</ion-label>
  <ion-label>xxx</ion-label><ion-label text-right>xxx</ion-label>
</ion-card-content></ion-card>
```

Cannot align "Total Price" and "Due Date" in the same line.I need to align "Total Price" to the left end and the "Due Date" to the right end! Give me the best solution guys!

[image: current view]

Comment: how does it show?

Comment: @suraj added the image url.please check

Comment: Thank you suraj! It's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using `ion-row` and `ion-col` to make sure your text appears in a single row.

```
 <ion-card>
<ion-card-content>
  <ion-row>
   <ion-col col-6>
    <ion-label>Total Price</ion-label>
   </ion-col>
   <ion-col col-6>
    <ion-label text-right>Due Date</ion-label>
   </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
   <ion-row>
    <ion-col col-6>
     <ion-label>xxx</ion-label>
    </ion-col>
    <ion-col col-6>
     <ion-label text-right>xxx</ion-label>
    <ion-col>
   <ion-row>
</ion-card-content></ion-card>
```